# Join all the boxes of 2 different labels into one label in Automl object detection

Tags: label, aggregate, object-detection, google-cloud-automl

Let's say I have been labeling my images to find cats and dogs. So I have a label called `Cats` and one called `Dogs`. But then I want a new training set to find pets. So I'd like to create a label called `Pets` and make all boxes labelled as `Cats` or `Dogs` to fall into the `Pets` label. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export dataset to csv and change labels cat or dogs to pets and reimport the labelled csv into a new dataset.